# C++ - What is the pipe ( | ) character?

Tags: c++

I have some code like:

```
#include "Communicate.h"

Communicate::Communicate(const wxString& title)
       : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(290, 150))
{
  m_parent = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);

  wxBoxSizer *hbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

  m_lp = new LeftPanel(m_parent);
  m_rp = new RightPanel(m_parent);

  hbox->Add(m_lp, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5);
  hbox->Add(m_rp, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5);

  m_parent->SetSizer(hbox);

  this->Centre();
}
```

from this tutorial:
http://zetcode.com/gui/wxwidgets/ - First Apps

What does operator | mean:

```
hbox->Add(m_lp, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5);
hbox->Add(m_rp, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5);
```

Comment: It's bitwise OR, nothing specific for wxwidgets or UI programming.

Comment: A beginner C tutorial would cover this. Please read.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request to teach core language features.

Comment: I don't ask about C. I ask about C++. I generally use || as OR but I haven't seen | operator before so I just ask. If it is sth 'inherited' from C, please just write it because tutorials using "clear" C are generally useless 4 me and I don't want to look into it only to know about simple | operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`|` is a bitwise OR.

Libraries generally define different masks, such as your `wxEXPAND` and `wxALL` which are usually integer constants with only one bit set.

When you use the bitwise-or operator, you can combine these to create what's called a bitfield, an integer with bits that you define set.

You combine these like this:

`wxEXPAND | wxALL`

which will create a bitfield with the bits from wxEXPAND and wxALL set.

Usually the library will then check if these bits are set like this for example:

`if (bitfield & wxEXPAND) { .. // wxEXPAND is set`

This is a bitwise AND.  The test will return true if and only if the `wxEXPAND` bit is set in `bitfield`.

Libraries use this to allow you to pass multiple options in a single register, for example.

Comment: *bitfield* means something else in C (it's a variety of `struct` member).